# Installing windows service using batch file failure-passwrd contains %

Tags: .net, windows, batch-file, windows-services, installation

In our project we are installing windows service using windows application where user enters username and password. when they click on submit we are running batch file where we are replacing username and password and running the batch file

Problem:The installation failed when password contains % character

My batch file content

```
@ECHO OFF


set DOTNETFX2=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX2%

echo Installing TestPrint Win Service...
echo ---------------------------------------------------
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil /username=domain\112233/password=5one0one4%  "%~dp0TestPrint.exe"
echo ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you tried to escape the percent sign: `/password=5one0one4%%`?

Comment: yes by escaping the % sign it is working.how can i do it the same in the batch file

Comment: I don`t understand what you are asking. If the password has the value escaped, what do you want to change in batch file?

Comment: intially the batch file contains "password" text then i am replacing the "password" text with user entered password.Is there any way i can handle the escape characters in batch file itself. Instead of handling it in c# code.

Comment: Instead of replacing the value in the installUtil command, use a variable `set "pwd=password"` replace the value in the variable assignment, and in installUtil use `/password=%pwd%`

Comment: i have tried as you suggested but in password text the % is missing.

Comment: For example set "pwd=5one0one4%" but in actual password it was 5one0one4

Comment: Well, it works for me. But if this does not work for you, then your best option is `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, `set "pwd=5one0one4%"` (replaced text), `set "pwd=!pwd:%%=%%%%!"`, and in installUtil maintain the `/password=%pwd%`

Comment: Anyway, you will have this same problem with any of `&<>|` Can you use quotes in the password parameter? Something like `/password="whatever"`?

Comment: I tried the the statements given by you but still have the same prblm

Comment: @ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set DOTNETFX2=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX2%

echo Installing TestPrint Win Service...
echo ---------------------------------------------------
set "pwd=5one0one4%"

set "pwd=!pwd:%%=%%%%!"

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil /username=xrxodc\394657 /password=%pwd% "%~dp0TestPrint.exe"
echo ---------------------------------------------------



pause
echo done

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I was testing in a wrong environment. No, there is no way to do it without changing your c# code. When cmd parser sees the non escaped % in batch file, it is removed.

Comment: You have two options, and the two needs changes in your c# code. Do the escaping to include the text in the batch file or pass the data as arguments to the batch file.

Comment: okay.Thanks for your time .I wil implement changes in  c# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the c# part. Just remember the arguments must be quoted for it to work

```
string _userName = @"xrxodc\394657";
string _password = @"5one0one4%";
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\somewhere\batchFile.cmd";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", _userName, _password)
proc.Start();
```

For the batch part

```
....
set "userName=%~1"
set "password=%~2"
....
.... InstallUtil /username=%userName% /password=%password%  "%~dp0TestPrint.exe"
```

And, i can not test it, but if it is allowed, you will need to change the syntax to

```
.... InstallUtil /username="%userName%" /password="%password%"  "%~dp0TestPrint.exe"
```

to avoid problems with special characters in passwords